# Screenshot process on login screen

Tags: 20.04, login

After every time I take a screenshot, a Screenshot process instance appears on the login screen:

[image]

They stay there until I reboot. Is there any way to prevent these from appearing, or even just remove this list of processes entirely from the login screen?

Comment: click the time on top bar and switch on "do not disturb"